# Multidomain Laravel App with partially same codebase

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-9

I am trying to implement a app, which provides two different login types based on the domain the user enters from. After successful login, the user gets a standard role and all users share the same codebase from here.

e.g.:

domain1.com leads to the standard auth scaffolding, regarding a login via email and pass

domain2.com leads to a controller which checks against an existing LDAP Login, gets additional info from the database at success and uses this info to log in the user via the standard auth api, additionally providing the role for the user.

So after the login is successful one way or the other, the user should share the same controllers, views, etc.

Is there any way to implement this? All answers I have found use some kinds of domaingroups to split the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using [laravel's subdomain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing).

As an example, suppose you have two domains domain1.com and domain2.com. You have a login route `login`

```php
Route::domain('domain1.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', function () {
        // login 
    });
});
Route::domain('domain2.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', function () {
        // login second method
    });
});

// Common routes
```

You can then make your web server (Apache, Nginx, etc) have the same folder as the document root for both domains. So then, when a request comes to any of these domains, your web server will make your Laravel application handle the request, and Laravel will decide which page/auth method to use based on the domain.

So users from domain1 will use the first login route, and users of domain2 will use the second login route.

If you have static files (js,CSS, etc ) and you use the local filesystem driver, you may get cors errors, so it would be best to upload them to some CDN and cloud storages. If that's not possible, you would need to dynamically change the URL returned based on domain.